# Как избежать двойной отправки письма?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Библиотека PHPMailer. Код такой:

```
$mailer = new \Model\PHPMaielrModel();
if(!empty($mail1)){
    $mailer->sendMail($mail1, $my, 'Тема 1', 'Текст 1');
}
$mailer->sendMail($mail2, $my, 'Тема 2', 'Текст 2');
```

На ящик `$mail1` так приходят оба письма и первое и второе, а нужно на каждый ящик по 1 письму. Пока поборол пересозданием объекта перед отправкой второго письма, но понимаю что это неправильно и должен быть правильный путь.

Comment: Это происходит из-за того, что $mail1 существует как объект. Возможно вам стоит придумать некий другой способ проверки на пустоту для этих переменных?

Comment: else не поможет разве?

Comment: @Ep1demic `$mail1` это не объект, это просто переменная с e-mail адресом. Объект это `$mailer`

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov нет потому что он с else отправит либо на 1 емайл либо на другой, а надо либо на один либо на оба.